# Invisible links in the footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, footer

In normal view footer contains a copyright block with couple of clickable links:

> [image: copyright block]

After group of sites being selected (e.g. Culture/Recreation) that block became invisible, but links are still clickable:

> [image: hidden links]

Same for:

> ```
> Blog Facebook Twitter LinkedIn
> ```

Comment: That's because they chose to hide the whole block by using `opacity: 0;` which leaves the element in place, just invisible. For this purpose, better use `display: none;` instead. /cc @Paweł. (Pretty sure he knows it already though :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fixed now and should be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).